# "Since" and tenses

Tags: relative-clauses

I have learned a rule that states: when **since** introduces an action in the past, we can use the *past simple* or *present perfect* after since and the *present perfect* in the main clause.

However, some sentences follow this rule, such as:

> 1.They haven't received any junk mail since they moved or have moved house.

other sentences contradict that rule:

> 2.They couldn't deliver the parcel since no one was there to answer the door.

or

> 3.Since her husband hated holidays so much, she decided to go on her own.

(both clauses, 2 and 3, are in the simple past)

Would you please explain...?

Answer (score 1):

In English language, words don't necessarily need to mean only one thing all the time. In your second and third examples ***since*** means ***because***, and has nothing to do with time.

> 2 [conjuction] **For the reason that; because.**
>
> delegates were delighted, since better protection of rhino reserves will help protect other rare species

[Oxford](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/since)

If you substitute that in your second and third examples they will make things clear. All 3 sentences are correct.